# No Such Table when trying to delete before data is put in

Tags: android, android-room

I am getting a `SQLiteException - no such table` when trying to delete from a table before data has actually been put in. I am using room.

My guess is that the table only gets created after the first data is inserted. However I have an operation that requires replacing data in the database with each request:

```
 override fun refreshList(filter: ApplyFilterRequest, page: Int, pageSize: Int, replace: Boolean): Single<FilterResponse> {

        var pagedResponseData: ResponseData = ResponseData.list(page, pageSize)
        var pagedFilter = filter.copy(responseData = pagedResponseData)

        return from(placesApi.applyFilter(pagedFilter))
                .doOnSuccess {

                    var list = it.list?.places
                    appDatabase.beginTransaction()
                    list?.let {
                        var listResult = list.map { ListResult(it.placeId) }
                        if(replace) {
                            listResultDao.replace(listResult)//We save each place on the database to be able to reference it by experienceId
                        }
                        else{
                            listResultDao.saveResults(listResult)
                        }
                        placesDao.savePlaces(it)
                    }
                    appDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
                    appDatabase.endTransaction()
                }
                .doOnError {
                    appDatabase.endTransaction()
                }
    }
```

And the replace operation:

```
 @Transaction
    open fun replace(ids: List<ListResult>) {
        deleteAll()
        saveResults(ids)
    }
@Query("DELETE from list_results")
abstract fun deleteAll()
```

This throws the following error:

```
Handling Error android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: room_table_modification_log (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE from list_results
        #################################################################
        Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
        Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
            (no such table: room_table_modification_log (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE from list_results)
        ################################################################# with text We couldn't get your places. Please try again.
        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: room_table_modification_log (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE from list_results
        #################################################################
        Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
        Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
            (no such table: room_table_modification_log (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE from list_results)
```

If data is already in place, then I get no error.

Comment: Can you add the deleteAll() function to the question

Comment: I just did that

Comment: Which version of Room you are using?

Comment: version is 1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

The solution to that problem is just to update your room version to a higher version than 1.1.0 because there is a known bug in this version you can use 1.1.1 or higher. Here is the bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79362399

Comment: can i get a link to the bug in question?